# How to change the color of a disabled html control in Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, javascript, html, internet-explorer

```
input[disabled='disabled']
{
    background-color:#FFFBF0;
    color: #28B51D;     
}
```

I am using the following code, but it doesn't work in IE.

It works in the rest of the Browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged your question as `javascript`, here is my advice for IE : include an ie-only script with an ie-triggering html comments, that adds a `ie-disabled` class to every disabled input. If the status of inputs can change after the initial page load, add a timed observer to your page that sets the class properly.

```
input[disabled], input.ie-disabled
{
    background-color:#FFFBF0;
    color: #28B51D;     
}
```

javascript file, included with conditional comment:

```
function checkDisabled() {   
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
  for(var i=0, l=inputs.length; i<l; i++) {
    if(inputs[i].disabled) {
        if(inputs[i].className.indexOf('ie-disabled')==-1)
      inputs[i].className = inputs[i].className+' ie-disabled';
    } else {
      inputs[i].className = inputs[i].className.replace('ie-disabled', '');
    }
  }
}


setInterval(checkDisabled, 1000); // check every second
```

[Here is a test](http://jsfiddle.net/LYfnY/) (for IE). Note that the color css attribute is ignored by IE for disabled inputs. If you really need a green text, use `readonly` instead of `disabled`.